# Changing nested XML element tags with the same name using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

The goal is to change nested XML element tags with the same name using XSLT.  I have tried using numbers and other methods.  I have not been able to obtain the desired result.

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<x>
    <y>
        <z value="john" designation="manager">
            <z value="mike" designation="associate"></z>
            <z value="dave" designation="associate"></z>
        </z>
   </y>
</x>
```

The XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="x">
    <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
        <employees>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </employees>    
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="y">
        <employee>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </employee> 
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="//x[y/z/@value='john' and y/z/@value='mike' and y/z/@value='dave']">
            <xsl:element name="{@designation}">
            <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
            </xsl:element>    
    </xsl:template>
```

The desired result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<employees>
    <employee>
        <manager>john
            <associate>mike</associate>
            <associate>dave</associate>
        </manager>
    </employee>
</employees>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the same solution as in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45799974/changing-xml-element-tag-using-xslt) - just add an `xsl:apply-templates` instruction in order to process the nested `z` elements recursively:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="x">
    <employees>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </employees>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="y">
    <employee>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </employee>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="z">
    <xsl:element name="{@designation}">
        <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you Michael, however my goal is to have the manager tag surround the associate tags.

Comment: @Kenny Yes, the hierarchy is preserved. Don't let the indentation (or lack thereof) confuse you.

Comment: I did test this and the manager tag was closed after the manager name for some reason.

Comment: @Kenny You can see it working here: http://xsltransform.net/pNmBy1B Note that there is no white space after "John". That is the correct result. Otherwise you would have to modify the actual value of the manager node.

Comment: My environment gives different results so I guess the issue is on my end.  I am using Windows 10, with Eclipse, Maven and Camel.  Thank you.

Comment: @Kenny Recheck your test, because this is pretty basic XSLT.